# Redirect all urls to non www https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, no-www

I have a dedicated server (Apache+Nginx (as proxy reverse) and php-fpm , mod-rewrite is activated), I host many domains and in one specific domain I want all requests to https://domain.com. I have tried many solutions and all theme but none worked for me.

Please give me a complete code to put in `.htaccess` to redirect The following:

```
domain.com
www.domain.com
https://www.domain.com
```

To:

```
https://domain.com
```

Comment: **please give me a complete code to put in htaccess** This is not give-me-code site, show what you've tried and we'll help you.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with programming. Throwing a flag now.

Answer (score 1):

you need write this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```